# Page Redirection for an aspx.net Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

My client wants to use a shorter URL for marketing of an event than the events page has. So I'm trying to set this up on their .aspx site in Microsoft Visual Studio on their web server.

I tried creating a new page that would have the URL they want to use and then just redirect that to the events page. Below is the code I entered on the page:

`<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/master/default.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<%@ Response.Redirect="http://www.happinesshouse.org/news/events.aspx" %>`

And that was it. It's giving a Parser Error Message: "The server block is not well formed."

I tried a bunch of other code but everything is throwing up errors. Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a URL shortener service?

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Redirect()` is a method, not a property; call it with parenthesis:

```
<%@ Response.Redirect("http://www.happinesshouse.org/news/events.aspx"); %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that still led the the same Parser Error Message. 

I didn't create this website and am not familiar with much of this language so it's kind of like fumbling through the dark looking for the light switch.

Comment: @S.Wow are you re-deploying the app when making changes? ASP.NET is typically compiled... Alternatively, you can just do a client-side redirect via JavaScript, or redirect via web hosting setup